# PCL-compatible Chr and Asc in VB?

Tags: vb.net, portable-class-library

I am porting an old VB code base to PCL-compatible format. I have managed to build new versions of things like Left and CInt, but Asc and Chr have me stumped. The typical answer is "import Microsoft.VisualBasic", but that does not exist in PCL.

In C# you simply cast the string to int to get the Unicode value. The equivalent would seem DirectCast in VB.net, but that does not work. Does anyone know how to write Asc and Chr in VB.net using PCL-compatible functions?

Comment: Chr and Asc became obsolete 19 years ago.  The odds that using them today is still correct are zilch, they are not compatible with Unicode.  Microsoft took the opportunity to get rid of them when they created the PCL profiles.  You must use ChrW and AscW, the Unicode compatible variants.

Comment: Also in Microsoft.VisualBasic, so equally not usable.

Comment: Hmm, that rings a bell.  Was it not you that keeps forgetting to mention that you target Xamarin profiles?  Which doesn't support VB.NET so you can't, you know, use it?  Use the Convert class.

Comment: I'm not using Xamarin in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF.GetString/GetBytes. These both work on arrays so you have to copy your input (an Int32 in my case) into a Byte() before going into GetString, and a Substring(0,1) into a Char() before going into GetBytes. This is, of course, more complex than the C# solution, where you can just cast the char/int. anyway...

```
   Public Function Asc(CharIn As String) As Integer
        Dim c As Char = Convert.ToChar(CharIn.Substring(0, 1))
        Dim cArray(0) As Char
        cArray(0) = c
        Return Convert.ToInt32(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cArray)(0))
    End Function
    Public Function Chr(NumIn As Integer) As String
        Dim bArray(0) As Byte
        Dim AscString As String
        bArray(0) = Convert.ToByte(NumIn)
        AscString = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(bArray)
        Return AscString
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following for Chr:

```
Public Shared Function Chr(NumIn As Integer) As String
    Dim bArray(0) As Byte
    Dim AscString As String
    bArray(0) = Convert.ToByte(NumIn)
    AscString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bArray, 0, 1)
    Return AscString
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Convert.ToChar` instead of `Chr` and `Convert.ToInt32` instead of `Asc`:

```
Dim c As Char = Convert.ToChar(65)      ' yields the character "A"
Dim i As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32("A"c)  ' yields 65
```

Both are available in PCL, even when targeting Xamarin.